# Loop through multiple sheets and delete every empty column in the given range

Tags: excel, vba

I want to loop through multiple sheets and delete every empty column in the given range.

I get

> Error 2023 and Run-time Error 13

on the if-statement.

```vb
Sub Delete_all_empty_columns_test2()

    Dim Areas(12) As Range, Idx As Integer, C As Range

    Set Areas(0) = Ark2.Range("C6:W6")
    Set Areas(1) = Ark4.Range("D11:X11")
    Set Areas(2) = Ark3.Range("D11:X11")
    Set Areas(3) = Ark3.Range("AC11:AW11")
    Set Areas(4) = Sheet1.Range("C6:W6")
    Set Areas(5) = Ark12.Range("C6:W6")
    Set Areas(6) = Ark11.Range("C6:W6")
    Set Areas(7) = Ark11.Range("AA6:AU6")
    Set Areas(8) = Ark14.Range("D11:X11")
    Set Areas(9) = Ark8.Range("D11:X11")
    Set Areas(10) = Ark9.Range("D11:X11")
    Set Areas(11) = Ark10.Range("D11:X11")
    Set Areas(12) = Sheet2.Range("E13:X13")

    For Idx = 0 To 12
        For Each C In Areas(12).Cells
            If C.Value = "0" Or C.Value = "" Or C.Value = "N/A" Then
                C.EntireColumn.Delete
            End If
        Next C
    Next Idx

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `IsError` to test if the cell is an error.

Answer (score -1):

Whereas you can easily loop through all sheets (or worksheets) the simplicity of the loop is defeated by the complexity of the differences between the tasks to be performed on each of them. When designing code you should identify repetitive tasks. In this case it's the deleting of blank columns.

When actually writing the code you need to work outward from the core. In this case the core is the test. `If C.Value = "0"` can't work because the value of a range is an array. Next task is to loop through the columns. You can't use For ... Each because you need to delete the last column first, because columns will change position when some of them are deleted.

Here is the code that results from the above logic.

```
Sub DeleteEmptyColumns(ByVal RngAddress As String, _
                       Ws As Worksheet)

    Dim C       As Long             ' loop counter: columns
    
    With Ws.Range(RngAddress)
        For C = (.Column + .Columns.Count - 1) To .Column Step -1
            With .Worksheet
                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(C)) = 1 Then
                    .Columns(C).EntireColumn.Delete
                End If
            End With
        Next C
    End With
End Sub
```

Call the sub with two parameters, the address of the column range to be examined and the worksheet on which it is found. In the next step you need a procedure to call the sub. The nature of this flows from the requirement of the sub-routine. Here it is.

```
Sub DeleteEmptyColumns_Main()

    DeleteEmptyColumns "C6:W6", Ark2
    DeleteEmptyColumns "D11:X11", Ark4
    
'    Set Areas(2) = Ark3.Range("D11:X11")
'    Set Areas(3) = Ark3.Range("AC11:AW11")
'    Set Areas(4) = Sheet1.Range("C6:W6")
'    Set Areas(5) = Ark12.Range("C6:W6")
'    Set Areas(6) = Ark11.Range("C6:W6")
'    Set Areas(7) = Ark11.Range("AA6:AU6")
'    Set Areas(8) = Ark14.Range("D11:X11")
'    Set Areas(9) = Ark8.Range("D11:X11")
'    Set Areas(10) = Ark9.Range("D11:X11")
'    Set Areas(11) = Ark10.Range("D11:X11")
    
    DeleteEmptyColumns "E13:X13", Worksheets("Sheet2")
End Sub
```

I didn't complete the typing task but it's easy to do. Note that you can even pass a single column as *RngAddresss* argument but it must be specified like "C:C". The worksheet can be specified using CodeNames (as your code does) or tab names, requiring syntax like `Worksheets("MyTab")` as shown for the last item above - just to show. It's better to stick with one method. The [dis-]advantage of CodeNames is that they don't change when the user changes the tab name.

Arguably, the task of calling the executing sub-routine could be simplified with loops in the `Main` but that is another question for another thread. I doubt that it's worth the effort because the volume of repetition is limited.

So, the only thing that remains to be done is to consider the scope of the sub-routine. Since it won't be called from anywhere except the `Main`, and should therefore be placed in the same module as the the `Main`, its scope need not be *Public* (which is the default) and should, therefore, be marked as `Private`.